# Jena Fuseki server on Mac Terminal

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I am new to Jena Fuseki server, so if I'm doing something silly or posting at the wrong place, please say so kindly!

Following the link http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/index.html, after I downloaded and unzipped it on my Mac, I tried to start the server using command line.

Even though I am in the same directory, I still specified the whole path, as I had read in some posts this was necessary:

```
$ /Users/H_Miri/Desktop/jena-fuseki-0.2.6/fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
```

But I get the following on my terminal, and then the curser is just stuck there:

```
10:11:23 INFO  Server               :: Dataset: in-memory
10:11:23 INFO  Config               :: Home Directory: /Users/hosseinmiri/Desktop/jena-fuseki-0.2.6
10:11:24 INFO  Server               :: Dataset path = /ds
10:11:24 INFO  Server               :: Fuseki 0.2.6 2013-02-20T12:04:26+0000
10:11:24 INFO  Server               :: Started 2013/03/14 10:11:24 CET on port 3030
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

H

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing at all. It's running! Try visiting `http://localhost:3030/`.

If you want fuseki to run in the background you could add a '&' to the end of the line:

```
$ /Users/H_Miri/Desktop/jena-fuseki-0.2.6/fuseki-server --update --mem /ds &
```

but personally I'd simply open up another terminal tab.

Answer (score 0):

command "fuseki-server --update --mem /ds" didnt work for me on Mac

Fuseki starts successfully after this terminal command :

"FUSEKI_HOME=Desktop/apache-jena-fuseki/ Desktop/apache-jena-fuseki/fuseki-server --mem /ds"